# For some reason RTINSTALLER64.exe keeps crashing when I try to install driver for: Realtek USB Ethernet Controller All-In-One Windows Driver

Tags: crash, windows-11, gigabit-ethernet

For some reason RTINSTALLER64.exe keeps crashing when I try to install driver for: Realtek USB Ethernet Controller All-In-One Windows Driver.

The installation still completes and everything shows up to date, but I am not sure why I keep seeing this in event log.

Any ideas?

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=133177565773951349
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=133177565781338265
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=f40b8964-75fa-4d80-acb5-7ea762081662
IntegratorReportIdentifier=352389a4-8320-4bde-9f61-7e8a647cb2df
Wow64Host=34404
NsAppName=RTINSTALLER64.EXE
OriginalFilename=RTInstaller.exe
AppSessionGuid=00001e60-0001-00ca-7986-9e5b4a24d901
TargetAppId=W:00003fc7178d6b988dccccf145ac0f40c7470000ffff!0000d772627e3c5a500ba6d68890bc473cc11ca817e1!RTINSTALLER64.EXE
TargetAppVer=2022//06//14:11:10:07!0!RTINSTALLER64.EXE
BootId=4294967295
TargetAsId=467
IsFatal=1
EtwNonCollectReason=1
Response.BucketId=f42195328b9e01efe88a1e6d5eee7a00
Response.BucketTable=4
Response.LegacyBucketId=1768259258789296640
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=RTINSTALLER64.EXE
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=62a86c8f
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=RTINSTALLER64.EXE
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=62a86c8f
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=000000000001c818
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.22621.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=6008
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=6008eacbe26a26e71bdf2b8ed2622565
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=8b60
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=8b60250319c86a6c5a80c641e0c07649
UI[2]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Realtek\Realtek USB Ethernet Controller All-In-One Windows Driver\RTINSTALLER64.EXE
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Realtek\Realtek USB Ethernet Controller All-In-One Windows Driver\RTINSTALLER64.EXE
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\ctiuser.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\newdev.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.DLL
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WOFUTIL.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVRTL.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\FLTLIB.DLL
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
```

Comment: Is the card compliant with Windows 11?  Do you have a Windows 11 Driver for it?

Comment: yes It is a Windows 11 driver that I got from Dell's website for my laptop. Since the driver seems to have updated, should i maybe just ignore it?